# Trying to connect to Facebook through the API

Tags: asp.net, facebook, api

I am trying to connect to Facebook through the API but it is giving me an error of Type:

> FacebookUser is not defined in vb file.

I have tried with namespaces but it is not working.
what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure FacebookUser.api is inside the handler. If possible to post part of code would be better to identify the issue.